# I can't use a Object, which was previously loaded via AJAX Request, in a function call

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension, that closes a tab when it's loaded and contains specific keywords, which I'm storing in `banned.json`. But following code gives me an error:

```
//background.js:
var obj;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
        obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
        console.log(obj.banned);
    }};
    xhttp.open('GET', "banned.json", true);
    xhttp.send();


    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, obj.banned); // error is here

    function closeTab(e) {
      if (!e.frameId) {
        console.log("Hallo2");
        chrome.tabs.remove(e.tabId);
      }
    }
```

It says that it cannot read property banned of undefined. How can that be? `obj` is defined in the first line and I can reference it in the `if-block`. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT:**
`banned.json`:

```
{
    "banned": [
        "https://www.google.de/",
        "youtube.com"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your object is not defined, it's only declared. by `var obj` you said `i have an obj var, but no value for now`. To define it, put an empty object there: `var obj = {}`

Comment: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
change banned.json to:

```
[
    "www.google.de",
    "www.youtube.com/?gl=DE"
]
```

"chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener" sentence mustn't be in "xhttp.onreadystatechange" function else you're gonna get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need put "chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener" sentence in "xhttp.onreadystatechange" function.

```
var obj;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
    obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
    console.log(obj.banned);
    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, obj.banned); 
}};
xhttp.open('GET', "banned.json", true);
xhttp.send();

function closeTab(e) {
  if (!e.frameId) {
    console.log("Hallo2");
    chrome.tabs.remove(e.tabId);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can try changing banned.json as follows.

```
{
    "banned": 
        "url" : [
            {"hostContains":"https://www.google.de/"},
            {"hostContains":"youtube.com"}
        ]
}
```

Comment: Ok, so first thanks for your answer. I've combined your solution with the note from the comments above and  declared obj with empty curly brackets:  
var obj = {};
but still that gives me an error:
Uncaught TypeError: could not convert filter.
This happens independent of running a real AJAX or a synchronous "AJAX" request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show me obj.banned returned by ajax call?
The error seems saying obj.banned is not correct type.

refer to below https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered

Comment: I'm gonna add it to the question

Comment: try changing banned.json. please check edited answer.